# Is the Session DB Performance Boost still necessary?

Tags: sql-database, session-state

I see that the section on optimizing SQL Session DB Performance that existed in the [Sitecore 8.1 documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/81/sitecore-experience-platform/en/walkthrough--configuring-a-shared-session-state-database-using-sql.html)  no longer exists in the [documentation for 9.1](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/walkthrough--configuring-a-private-session-state-database-using-sql.html).

Is this because the step is no longer necessary or recommended? 
Should I still perform this step for a new Sitecore 9.1 installation?

Comment: Personally, i have never implemented that optimization in the past as session state performance was never an issue. On a high traffic site, I would consider using Redis instead.

Comment: Session state performance can absolutely be a performance issue on SQL. I can't imagine that there would be any fundamental difference in 9.1. However, I also wouldn't run something that isn't documented.